# VBA validation formula

Tags: excel, vba, validation

When I highlight an entire column, and set up data validation with the following parameters, it works fine: [image]

Formula is: `=OFFSET(CleanJobs!$E$2,,,COUNTIF(CleanJobs!$E$2:$E$30,"?*"))`. Input Message and Error Alert are both disabled. Validation works great via the UI. When I try to put the validation into VBA, I get a "Run-Time error '1004'; Application-defined or object-defined error" The code for the validation is

```
With wsTo.Range("D:D").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
    Operator:=xlBetween, _
    Formula1:="=OFFSET(CleanJobs!$E$2,,,COUNTIF(CleanJobs!$E$2:$E$30,""?*"")"
    .ShowInput = False
    .ShowError = False
End With
```

I can't figure out what the difference is. The formula is the same.

Comment: `Formula1` in your `VBA` code lacks a closing parenthesis at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please check your formula again?
In the UI, you have given this formula
`=OFFSET(CleanJobs!$E$2,,,COUNTIF(CleanJobs!$E$2:$E$30,"?*"))`
But, in your code, there seems to be a missing bracket at the end. Try the following

```
With wsTo.Range("D:D").Validation
  .Delete
  .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Operator:=xlBetween, _
  Formula1:="=OFFSET(CleanJobs!$E$2,,,COUNTIF(CleanJobs!$E$2:$E$30,""?*""))"
  .ShowInput = False
  .ShowError = False
End With
```